# reload current state with different params using angular2 router

Tags: angular, angular-routing

here's an example of my router:

```
{
    path: ':lang',
    component: MainComponent
    children: [
      {path: 'page1', component, children},
      {path: 'page2', component, children},
      ...
    ]
  },
```

examples of possible variants in URL are:

- `/en/page1`
- `/es/page1/child`

As you can see, the very first parameter is a `lang` which means page's language and after that it's just a path to children pages.

I need to create a link which will reload current state but with different param (language in my case), like this:
`/en/path/to/child/page` -> `/es/path/to/child/page`

**and the most difficult part for me** is this:

I don't want to hardcode `/path/to/child/page` in the `[routherLink]`, it should be dynamic. Maybe taken from `ActivatedRoute` but I haven't found a way how to do it yet

**it should be a link**, like this `<a [routerLink]="??">Spanish</a>`, **not** a method in controller, like: `this.router.navigate(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
this.path = '/path/to/child/page';
```

To make the other part is dynamic

```
<a [routerLink]="[lang, path]">{{lang}}</a>
```

In the route you specify path

`/:lang/path/to/child/page`

Comment: that's the point, I need everything after `/:lang/` to be dynamic. Sorry I didn't mention it

Answer (score 0):

If all your urls are build using same naming convention - the first url part is your language - you can use next solution:

Your link will looks like:

```
<a [routerLink]="['en', getContentUrl()]">Documents</a>
```

And `getContentUrl` can be part of your resolver service which takes current url and trim only data-related path (skip first part)

```
constructor(private route: Router) {
}

getContentUrl() {
    var urlParts = this.route.url.split('/');

    urlParts.shift();
    return urlParts.join('/');
}
```